# JavaScript and HTML Button onclick() Not working

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

So I've spent the past hour trying to figure out why when I click on the button nothing is happening... Normally User should enter a number and if it is a square number it will add all the digits.. But my code is doing nothing! Please help!

```js
function analyzeNumber() {
  var input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

  alert("User value" + input);

  document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = input;

  if ((validateNumber(input)) == true) {
    if (Math.sqrt(input) % 1 === 0) {
      var total = sumDigits(input);
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = total;
    } else {
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = " ";
      alert("It is not a square number!");
    }
  }
}

function validateNumber(b) {
  if ((typeof.b == "number") && (b > -1)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
    alert("Please enter numeric value!");
  }
}

function sumDigits(a) {
  var str = input.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> SOEN 287 Assignment 2 </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Q1.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <h1> Question 1</h1>
    <form action="" id="sqrForm">
      <p>
        <label>Please enter a number: <input type = "text" id = "user_input" /></label>
        <input id="btton" type="submit" value="Try it!" onclick="return analyzeNumber()" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label id="answer"> Answer: </label>
        <label id="answer_display"> </label>
      </p>
    </form>
  </fieldset>





</body>
```

Comment: The `alert`s after your `return` is unreachable. Don’t use `alert` to debug. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Oh! I was not sure! And if I just don't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

> The `typeof` operator is followed by its operand where
>   operand is an expression representing the object or primitive whose type is to be returned.

Change

```
if((typeof.b == "number") && (b > -1)){
```

To

```
if((typeof(b) == "number") && (b > -1)){
```

Comment: Oh okay I changed that! Sorry it's my first time with HTML & JS so I'm still learning :S

Answer (score 0):

A little hint for the future: 
don't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log()` or `console.info()` together with your dev tools in your browser (opens when pressing F12).

---

You need to change `typeof.b` to either `typeof b` or `typeof(b)`.

```js
function analyzeNumber() {
  var input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

  alert("User value" + input);

  document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = input;

  if ((validateNumber(input)) == true) {
    if (Math.sqrt(input) % 1 === 0) {
      var total = sumDigits(input);
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = total;
    } else {
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = " ";
      alert("It is not a square number!");
    }
  }
}

function validateNumber(b) {
  if ((typeof b == "number") && (b > -1)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
    alert("Please enter numeric value!");
  }
}

function sumDigits(a) {
  var str = input.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> SOEN 287 Assignment 2 </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Q1.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <h1> Question 1</h1>
    <form action="" id="sqrForm">
      <p>
        <label>Please enter a number: <input type = "text" id = "user_input" /></label>
        <input id="btton" type="submit" value="Try it!" onclick="return analyzeNumber()" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label id="answer"> Answer: </label>
        <label id="answer_display"> </label>
      </p>
    </form>
  </fieldset>





</body>
```

---

Something you should be aware of:

When you click the button to fire the script, the `form` submits and your output "disappears". To prevent that, change the `type` of your `input` from `submit` to `button`:

```js
function analyzeNumber() {
  var input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

  alert("User value" + input);

  document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = input;

  if ((validateNumber(input)) == true) {
    if (Math.sqrt(input) % 1 === 0) {
      var total = sumDigits(input);
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = total;
    } else {
      return document.getElementById("answer_display").innerHTML = " ";
      alert("It is not a square number!");
    }
  }
}

function validateNumber(b) {
  if ((typeof b == "number") && (b > -1)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
    alert("Please enter numeric value!");
  }
}

function sumDigits(a) {
  var str = input.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> SOEN 287 Assignment 2 </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Q1.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <h1> Question 1</h1>
    <form action="" id="sqrForm">
      <p>
        <label>Please enter a number: <input type = "text" id = "user_input" /></label>
        <input id="btton" type="button" value="Try it!" onclick="return analyzeNumber()" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label id="answer"> Answer: </label>
        <label id="answer_display"> </label>
      </p>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah thank you!! Yeah now I'm seeing I'm mixing Java with Javascript and HTML ugh.. Sorry for beginner mistakes!

Comment: @GooseLooking No need to excuse! Everybody has to start somewhere!

Comment: Oh so I actually manage to make it work! But somehow if I enter "4" which is a square number, on the HTML page it will show the sum of its digits which is "4" for not even half a second before disappearing of the page... Is it normal? :O

Comment: AH found it! I needed to add "; return false" onclick :)

Comment: @GooseLooking Yes, that happens when your form gets submitted. Forms are usually for sending data to a backend like a server. To prevent the form from submitting, just add  - like you just discovered - `return false` to your `onclick` attribute, make use of `event.preventDefault()` or go the way I explained in the "Something you should be aware of:" section of my post. Glad you got it to work.